# Facebook login crashes my app due to NSException

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, firebase, nsunknownkeyexception

So with the updated Facebook SDK to enable a user to login to my app, I seem to not be able to get it to work properly! I am using code based off of Firebase's guide since that is what I am trying to integrate it with.

I am getting frustrated with it and cannot get the below error to stop terminating my app. I have all of the proper .plist info entered, I have the cocoa pods installed, and all of the SDK folders that are required. PLEASE HELP!

My code displays no errors, but when I build and run and then click on the Facebook button I get: "libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb) "

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func fbButtonPressed(sender: UIButton!) {

    let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()

        facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: self) { (facebookResult: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, facebookError: NSError!) -> Void in

        if facebookError != nil{
            print("Facebook login failed. Error\(facebookError)")
        } else {
            let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
            print("Succesfully logged in with Facebook. \(accessToken)")
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is my Crashlog:

```
2016-04-03 18:24:14.425 ABH5[23068:3428052] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key fbButtonPressed.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010444cd85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001068f0deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010444c9c9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x0000000104ee619b -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 288
    4   UIKit                               0x00000001054cfd0c -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 88
    5   UIKit                               0x00000001057067fb -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104386890 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001057051de -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1864
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001054d68d6 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 381
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001054d7202 -[UIViewController loadView] + 178
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001054d7560 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 138
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001054d7cd3 -[UIViewController view] + 27
    12  UIKit                               0x00000001053adfb4 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 61
    13  UIKit                               0x00000001053ae69d -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 282
    14  UIKit                               0x00000001053c0180 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
    15  UIKit                               0x0000000105334ed9 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 4131
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010533b568 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1769
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000105338714 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 188
    18  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000108b758c8 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    19  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000108b75741 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 178
    20  FrontBoardServices                  0x0000000108b75aca -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104372301 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010436822c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001043676e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001043670f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    25  UIKit                               0x0000000105337f21 -[UIApplication _run] + 402
    26  UIKit                               0x000000010533cf09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    27  ABH5                                0x00000001036a7dd2 main + 114
    28  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001073b492d start + 1
    29  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```